# Question About Foreach and List Iteration

Tags: c#, list, foreach, linked-list, iteration

I've been reading about `foreach` and list iteration, and I understand how to set it up.

What I have not been able to find throughout my research is how to iterate more than once. To better explain, here is my specific example:

I'm creating an A* path request manager that divides a given number of search cycles out over each request. So it will need to iterate through its `LinkedList` of requests, handing out one search cycle per request. Given that it starts with 1000 cycles, needless to say, it will need to go through its list of requests more than once in order to evenly distribute all of its cycles.

How can I ensure that the list will continue to iterate? Would this be a better task for a `while` or `for` loop? Or is there a way to do it with `foreach`?

In the event it would help anyone to further understand my question, here is my code as I have it now:

```
    //Method: UpdateSearches()
    //Purpose: to distribute all available search cycles
    //         between all active searches
    //         if a search completes or fails during this
    //         update, this method will notify the pathfinder
    //         who made the request
    //Parameters: none 
    //Returns: nothing
    public void UpdateSearches()
    {
        //start off with a full number of cycles
        int cyclesRemaining = this.searchCyclesPerUpdate;

        //cycle through all active requests
        foreach (Pathfinder request in this.searchRequests)
        {
            while ((cyclesRemaining > 0) && 
                   (this.searchRequests.Count != 0))
            {
                //one search cycle
                SearchStatus result = request.OneCycle();

                //if the search completes (success or failure)
                if (result == SearchStatus.targetFound ||
                    result == SearchStatus.targetNotFound)
                {
                    //remove this request from the queue
                    this.searchRequests.Remove(request);
                } //end if

                //move on to the next request
                cyclesRemaining--;
            } //end while
        } //end foreach
    } //end method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection that you are iterating, the following code would throw an exception at runtime:

```
    foreach (Pathfinder request in this.searchRequests)
    {
         //remove this request from the queue
         this.searchRequests.Remove(request);
    } //end foreach
```

In order to iterate more than once, place your foreach within another loop construction. After all, doesn't seem that foreach is the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Thank you. Would it work better to put the while loop outside the foreach, then?

Comment: And in regards to removing completed/failed searches, I understand what you're saying about modifying the list while iterating it. But how, then, do I ever move through the list to find the requests that have completed/failed and remove them?

Comment: Probably, but you still cant remove requests from searchRequest while iterating through it. You may store them in a requestToRemoves collection, and remove all of them after the foreach.

Comment: I see. Then I would be iterating the second list while removing from the first. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would not use a List for this but a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) or [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) - you `Enqueue` for example the 1000 requests... then you use a `while` loop with a condition on `Count > 0` to iterate the content of it... you `Dequeue` a request and execute it... if it needs to be re-executed then you just `Enqueue` it again... this way it will be added back but to the end so the execution stays fair/even.

Comment: I'm only a week into C#, and I haven't heard of a built-in Queue. Thanks for pointing this out to me - now there's more I can research on.